# What kind of links are accepted in an Amazon review?

Tags: amazon

I wrote an Amazon review, and the two links I had added in the review were replaced by [...]. What kind of links are accepted in an Amazon review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Amazon, they do not allow outside links in reviews. If your link would lead the reader away from the Amazon website, then it will be deleted or "Unlinked".

However, they do allow you to link to products on the Amazon website by using the ASIN number found on the product page.

The link must be formatted as follows:

```
[[ASIN:asin text for link]]
```

The ASIN number is found on the product page, usually where it lists product weight and other stats. Simply place that number within the brackets.

Example:

```
[[ASIN:B07WWWHSSC]]
```